# HTML select with items shown horizontally

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Good morning,

I'm developing a web application and I need an horizontal input that lets the user select a value, but radio buttons are not an option.
I thought about using a input with range type, but this is not supported in IE 8 or 9.
Is there any way to show select options horizontally that works both in chrome and IE?

My html code is:

```
<select size="4">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

It currently looks like this:

[image: Select]

Is there any way to make the options show side by side? I tried adding inline-block display to the options, but nothing changes.

--- EDIT ---

I don't want to use radio buttons because I'm using js to create new items which the user can also select and with radio buttons I have to change the button names manually.

[image: Multiple selects]

Comment: Can you elaborate on why radio buttons aren't an option?

Comment: I've never seen something like a select with a horizontal layout.  Do you have an example we can see?  I'm having a hard time envisioning something like this without it being... unusual.

Comment: This seems to be a wierd idea, you shouldn't do that. What's wrong with standard select drop down

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Edited my question to explain why I don't want radio buttons. My options are actually values such as "good", "excellent" and "bad" so I think it would be easier to select if they are always visible and more natural if side-by-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize you've already accepted an answer, however [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/qc2sz9op/) works too.
You can customize anything you want in it, including borders, background colours, etc.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"><span class="user">User 1</span>

    <div class="selectOptions">
        <div class="myOptions">
            <div class="option volvo">Volvo</div>
            <div class="option saab">Saab</div>
            <div class="option mercedes">Mercedes</div>
            <div class="option audi">Audi</div>
        </div>
        <div class="select user1">User 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#ddd;
    padding:5px;
    padding-bottom:7px;
}
.user {
    float:left;
    background-color:#ddd;
    margin-top:2px;
    padding:5px;
}
.user:after {
    content:":";
}
.selectOptions {
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.select {
    border:2px solid #333;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#ddd;
}
.select:hover {
    background-color:grey;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.myOptions {
    position:absolute;
    top:45px;
    /*42px (height of .select + (padding*2) minus border thickness*/
    border:2px solid #333;
    display:none;
    background-color:#ddd;
}
.option {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
}
.option:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-left:-5px;
}
.option:hover {
    background-color:#123456;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".select").hover(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".myOptions").css("display", "block");
    $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
}, function () {
    $(this).siblings(".myOptions").css("display", "none");
});
$(".myOptions").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("display", "block");
}, function () {
    $(this).css("display", "none");
    $(this).siblings(".select").css("background-color", "#ddd");
});
$(".option").hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#123456");
}, function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#ddd");
    var selection = $(this).html();
    if (selection == $(this).parent().siblings(".select").html()) $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
});
$(".option").click(function () {
    var selection = $(this).html();
    $(this).parent().siblings(".select").html(selection);
    $(this).siblings().css("background-color", "#ddd");
    $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you're after?

```
select {
    display:table-row;
}
option {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rjmnmcru/

Comment: I changed the select size on your fiddle to 1 and it looks to be a pretty neat technique.  http://jsfiddle.net/rjmnmcru/1/

Comment: This only works in Firefox. On a side note, I'm pretty sure it *shouldn't* be doing this in Firefox, either.

Comment: Yeah, I just discovered that.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work in chrome, and I need it to work specifically for chrome and IE. But thanks for the help

Comment: It doesn´t work at all, not even in Firefox 

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably to use either checkboxes, or an unordered list with links:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul.selections   { list-style:none; }
    ul.selections li    {display: inline; list-style-type: none; padding-right: 20px;}

    div.selections input { margin-left:15px;}
    div.selections input.first { margin-left:20px; }
</style>

<div class="selections">
    <input type="checkbox" value="volvo" class="first"/> Volvo
    <input type="checkbox" value="saab"/> Saab
    <input type="checkbox" value="mercedes"/> Mercedes
    <input type="checkbox" value="audi"/> Audi
</div>

<ul class="selections" >
    <li><a href="#" value="volvo">Volvo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" value="saab">Saab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" value="mercedes">Mercedes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" value="audi">Audi</a></li>
</ul>
```

you can use the links or onchecked of the checkboxes to fire JS events.  To make it clear to the end user, you can add a "highlight" class to the elements from the JS event, and change the background colors as necessary.

Comment: I wanted a only CSS solution. Or at least a simpler solution, but I think I'll have to use js to do this.

Comment: If you change your size to 1, instead of 4, it will give you your options in a drop down.  Because this control is intended for use as a drop down/multi-select there are no child element handles for applying CSS rules.